# Different MD5 hash in URL for login

Tags: objective-c, md5

I'm trying to develop an application that logs into a web service using a URL with specific strings. The URL reads so: `https://privateurl/Page.aspx?pid=302&t=TIME_SINCE_1970_IN_SECONDS&u=USERNAME&m=PASSWARD_IN_MD5_FORM`

I'm good with the username and time parts, but each time I sign into the website, the MD5 hash is different. But with my NSString+MD5 class, for the password string I put in, produces the same hash each time.

Why is this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, in what specific case is the md5 always different ?

Comment: Each time a user logs in, the password he/she enters into the field is hashed in the URL, but when the user signs out and signs back in, the hash is different.

Comment: Well, MD5 of the same string CAN'T be different. Did you tried to compare the bytes inside the string and see what changed ? Did you used salt ?

Comment: I haven't tried, no, but I will, thanks. No I haven't used salt, what is that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) tl;dnr: It's a way to strengthen hashed password by appending a string to it.